Necessity of the Hahn-Banach Extension Theorem Over Trivial Extensions
"Any bounded linear functional on a subspace admits a norm-preserving bounded linear extension". Why is this considered a special result? Can't the trivial extension (extending by zero for bases outside the subspace) serve the purpose of the Hahn-Banach extension theorem? Are there any counterexamples where the trivial extension is not norm-preserving or violates the conclusion of the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Existence of bases cannot be proved in ZF, but requires AC.  More, even with known bases, the "trivial" extension we get using them may not preserve norm (even in $2$ dimensions).

Could u please illustrate with a counter example, why trivial extensions don't preserve the norm

It doesn't always work. Here is a counterexample. Look at $\mathbb R^2$, and the subspace $L=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. Define the map $f\colon L\to\mathbb R$ sending $(x,x)\mapsto x$. Then,
$$|f((x,x))|=|x|=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\|(x,x)\|$$
And so $\|f\|=1/\sqrt2$.
However, take the basis $\{(1,1)\}$ of $L$ and extend it to the basis $\{(1,1),(1,0)\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$. Then, define $\tilde{f}\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ as
$$\tilde{f}(a(1,1)+b(1,0))=a$$
It is easy to see that $\tilde{f}$ is just the map $\tilde{f}(x,y)=y$. Then, $\tilde{f}$ cannot have norm $1/\sqrt2$ since
$$\left|\tilde{f}(0,1)\right|=1=\|(0,1)\|$$
Hope this helps. :)
